# How I can configure my laravel app for make a dynamic layout?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, routes, laravel-blade

I'm making a Laravel 10 project to try a make a dynamic layout.
My principal layout, is header sticky with a left navbar, the rest of the content is the other blades templates, with `@extends('layouts.app')` and `@section('content')`.

My problem is that i need make "the rest of content" dynamic layout.

- One column class="col-3" to show a `<ul>` as categories.
- Other column class="col-3" display none, to show a list of a products with the category selected in the first column, this column is started display none, and we u press a category i want to refresh this column and appear all projects with the category selected.
- 3Column class="col" to fill the rest of content and make some responsive, this section is dedicated to show the info of the product selected in the column 2.

---

I tried to make a ajax post in my created js file, but i cant get dynamic routes passing info, i don't know how reload only the section that i need, for example, if i press 1 column (categories), refresh only the products, but not all the page.

Using javascript ajax method and passing crsf token i get a "method not allowed" ERROR

I tried too, call `products.show` method in controller with a `$id` variable to get a category_id

I'm thinking about its possible hide and show sections, and don't use ajax request in javascript.

Anyone have any idea o can send me some guide.

PD: I have all my tables in BBDD with foreign keys, trying to make a constraints and cascade updating

If u need some more, tell me. I don't need a code, I need a guide to make this process, using js post request or using only Laravel blades and routing if it's possible build this.

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Yes you are applying the correct technique ajax calls (either via jQuery or axios). Also if possible attach a screenshot of what you want and where.

Answer (score 0):

Make a blade template with only the first column with the categories loaded and the skeleton of the second and third column.

```php
<div>
  <div class="categories">
    @foreach($categories as $category)
      ...
    @endforeach
  </div>
  <div class="products"></div>
  <div class="details"></div> 
</div>
```

Now register an "on click" event on the categories and make an ajax call to get the projects of that category and fill the skeleton of the second column with them.

```js
$(`.category`).click(fn(e) => {
  axios.get(`{{ route('projects.data') }}`, {
    params: {
      category_id: e.target.dataset.category
    }
  }).then(function (response) {
    document.getElementById("lista_projectos").innerHTML = response;
  })

})
```

```php
public function projectsData(Request $request)
{
  $projects = Projects::query()->where('category_id', $request->category_id)->get(); // maybe apply a limit here
  return response()->view('liberta.projectosbar', ['projects' => $data]);
}
```

Do the same for the third column.

Comment: Yes, this its my purpose, but how i cant charge projects filtering by have a category id. I edit the post with my code of html. Ohter wuestion its how i send request to controller of laravel via Jquery. I received method not allowed

Comment: have you defined the relation of categories and projects as belongs to or many to many?

Comment: 1 project only can have 1 category. And 1 category can have so many projects

Comment: ok so on the projects table you would have a category_id field you can filter by. as for the request you should have another endpoint that returns filtered projects by rendering the parcial `liberta.projectosbar`.

Comment: I have this, the problem now, is that the endpoint render other view, and i cant hide or show divs dinamically

Comment: "endpoint render other view" - why???

Comment: @Jesuuus23 if this was useful you can mark it as the answer